# $compile'ing already compiled elements is not supported, what to do then?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

According to [lgalfaso on Angular.js repo](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9171):

> lgalfaso commented 8 hours ago
>
> Recompiling an already compiled element is an abuse and not something
>   supported. I do not know what you are trying to do, but looks like a
>   topic for stackoverflow

The presented plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Y7FbPm?p=preview with code

```js
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('Main', function(){
    this.label = "Hello";
})
.directive('recompileMe', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function(el, attrs){
            el.removeAttr('recompile-me');

            return function(scope, el){
                $compile(el)(scope, function(clone) {
                    el.replaceWith(clone);
                });
            };
        }
    }    
}])
.directive('transcludeMe', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<div>Transcluded: <div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        link: function(scope, el, attr, controller, transclude){
        }
    }    
}]);
```

if I need to to set other directives to my element, I need to $compile it for the directive to be parsed and applied, or is there any other way? (another case of this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9169)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only correct way of doing this (even after scavenging angular.js source code), is to use `terminal: true`. That is, you will have to compile your element manually, and then do your DOM manipulation, like this:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('main', ['$scope', function($scope){ 
  $scope.inner = 'Inner content';
}])
.directive('recompileMe', ['$compile', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    terminal: true,
    priority: 10,
    compile: function(element){
      element.removeAttr('recompile-me');
      
      var compiled = $compile(element);

      return function(scope, el){
        compiled(scope);
      };
    }
  }
}])
.directive('transcludeMe', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div>Transcluded: <div ng-transclude></div></div>'
  };
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="main">
      <div recompile-me transclude-me><div ng-bind="inner"></div> Outside</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to compile once, you can detach the children of the directive's element before compilation reaches the element's children.  Then, add directives to the children, or manipulate the DOM as much as you like.  In the link phase, re-attach the children, and use the $compile service to compile and link the children.

```
.directive('recompileMe', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function(el, attrs){
            // save the children
            var e2 = angular.element(el.html());

            // clear the children so they are not compiled
            el.empty();

            // add some directives
            e2.find('a').attr('my-directive', '');

            return function(scope, el){

                // reattach to DOM
                el.append(e2);

                // compile and link children
                $compile(e2)(scope);
           };
        }
    }    
}])
```

Comment: the problem is that I'm also trying with childless tags like inputs... I tried using outerHTML, but it doesn't work (infinite recursion)